# Unable to cast List<int[*]> to List<int[]> instantiated with reflection

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

I am instantiating a `List<T>` of single dimensional `Int32` arrays by reflection. When I instantiate the list using:

```cs
Type typeInt = typeof(System.Int32);
Type typeIntArray = typeInt.MakeArrayType(1);
Type typeListGeneric = typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>);
Type typeList = typeListGeneric.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeIntArray, });

object instance = typeList.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
```

I see this strange behavior on the list itself:

[image: Watch of the list instance as an object]

If I interface with it through reflection it seems to behave normally, however if I try to cast it to its actual type:

```cs
List<int[]> list = (List<int[]>)instance;
```

I get this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32[*]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32[]]'.

Any ideas what may be causing this or how to resolve it? I am working in visual studio 2010 express on .net 4.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `MakeArrayType` function. The way you're using it you create a multidimensional array with one dimension, which is not the same as a one dimensional array (vector).

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0ykk2sw.aspx):

> The common language runtime makes a distinction between vectors (that is, one-dimensional arrays that are always zero-based) and multidimensional arrays. A vector, which always has only one dimension, is not the same as a multidimensional array that happens to have only one dimension. You cannot use this method overload to create a vector type; if rank is 1, this method overload returns a multidimensional array type that happens to have one dimension. Use the MakeArrayType() method overload to create vector types.

Change:

```
Type typeIntArray = typeInt.MakeArrayType(1);
```

to this:

```
Type typeIntArray = typeInt.MakeArrayType();
```

to create an ordinary one-dimensional vector.

Comment: I'd be curious as to why it causes that weird list behavior when viewing the locals too but for now, this problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0ykk2sw.aspx) says about `MakeArrayType(int)`:

> You cannot use this method overload to create a vector type; if rank
>   is 1, this method overload returns a multidimensional array type that
>   happens to have one dimension. Use the `MakeArrayType()` method overload
>   to create vector types.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my confusion between [] and [*] too!